# Increasing .NET knowledge

Tags: .net

I would like to see if anyone can offer any advise on furthering my knowledge in the .NET environment...

Here a little background.  I went to a university and got my BS in Computer Science (mostly worked in C, Java, and C++).  Took a job right out of college for a small business doing internal development and a few commercial projects as a one man show.  I do pretty much all my development in the .NET environment and most everything was self-taught.  It is now 3+ years later.

I feel that I'm not using proper procedures (configuring, creating, maintaining, etc my projects in VS), using the technologies to their fullest potential, improper techniques, or just using some things wrong.  I happy with the products I release and proud of the work I do, sometimes I just feel like I'm doing things wrong.

Can anyone make some suggestions (non-virtual environment) to becoming a better developer?  Good .NET communities in TX (specifically San Antonio)?  Or a book you consider to be a 'bible' when it comes to this stuff --being that I already own quite a few.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Download an open-source project and look at their methods of application organization. Paint.NET is a good one to start.

Another good method is to Google something you've already accomplished and see the way the smart masses have done it. Make sure they're actually doing something better before you adopt their methods though.

Comment: Paint.NET has one thing to be aware of though, if I remember correctly it uses unmanaged code for some of the image manipulation stuff so with that in mind one can learn much from it.

Also the Enterprise Library from Microsoft is an "open source" project in .net where it's possible to learn good practices.

Comment: Paint.NET source is no longer available.

Comment: Ah, shoot. That's unfortunate. Check out codeplex.com for projects, then.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend checking out the NerdDinner tutorial if you haven't already done so - although it does focus on Web Applications which may not be your thing... it blew my mind...

http://tinyurl.com/aspnetmvc

Comment: Web Applications is my thing.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Scott Guthrie is the Corporate VP of Microsoft's Developer Division. He is also an avid blogger, tweeter, and all around brilliant genius of a developer. He's not a stuffy shirted on the course golfing sort either. He really keeps up with the technology, he lives it. At any rate he writes some great example code and gives it out freely often. I have learned a lot of technique from him and he's well worth the read if you want to increase your .Net knowledge.

[Scott's Blog](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/)

[Scott's Twitter](http://twitter.com/scottgu)

[A series on .Net 4 by Scott Guthrie](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2009/08/25/vs-2010-and-net-4-series.aspx)

Comment: I'm going to have to second this. Guthrie is an awesome resource, you can tell he loves his job.

Comment: I noticed someone else mentioned NerdDinner above, which is a Scott Guthrie tutorial for a book he wrote, and gave away, for free! He is awesome! And I don't want to get into a Holy war of course, but I think he really had upped the image of Microsoft development over the years. Well done to him!

Comment: Couldn't agree more, I have learned a great deal from his stuff and use his site regularly.

Answer (score 0):

".NET Development" covers such a huge amount of things, you are going to get a wide array of information across the board on this.  Even when I look at the tags and see "web-development" - that could mean a lot of different things as well.

My suggestion, if you want to learn more, pick out the technology that you're interested in (ASP.NET MVC, WebForms, Javascript/jQuery, whatever) and hop onto Amazon and find a good book that can help you get started.  Once you have gone through the book, take those skills and try to apply them to your own web site (create a personalized one), or apply it directly to your job.

Answer (score 0):

You can improve your skills in .NET programming languages by:

- Professional tutorials.
- Pass tests.
- Check advanced free .NET open source projects.
- Apply complex functionality practically that similar in free .NET open source projects.

Also notice that practicing and implementing projects on every new function you learn is the key to raise your strength in that technology, plus checking advanced free demos, code review, how to overcome some complex functionalities and the new technologies beside .NET.

Answer (score -2):

First off before you worry about your .Net knowledge if you really want to be successful in the business world you need to worry about your writing skills.  "I would like to see if anyone CAN offer".

The average developer is so-so at their communication abilities (in fact the average person is only so-so) so by spending time learning how to communicate better and more clearly you'll have a huge advantage.

Second off before I worried about .Net in particular I'd worry about my core skills.  A great place to start is here...

http://blog.jpboodhoo.com/BuildASolidCore.aspx

Comment: Duly noted, your a life saver.  Thought you find this insightful http://www.libraryonline.com/default.asp?pID=29.

Comment: Thank you for the link.  That is definitely something I need to work on.